# python - How do I calculate the similarity between pairs of documents and queries?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have a very large dataset which is essentially document - search query pairs and I want to calculate the similarity for each pair. I've calculated the TF-IDF for each of the documents and queries. I realize that given two vectors you can calculate the similarity using linear_kernel. However, I'm not sure how to do this on a very large set of data (i.e. no for loops).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel

df_train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
doc_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_train["document"])
query_tfidf = vectorizer.transform(df_train["query"])

linear_kernel(doc_tfidf, query_tfidf)
```

Now this gives me an NxN matrix, where N is the number of document-query pairs I have. What I am looking for is N-size vector with a single value per document-query pair.

I realize I could do this with a for loop, but with a dataset of about 500K pairs this would not work. Is there some way that I could vectorize this calculation?

**UPDATE:** So I think I have a solution that works and seems to be fast. In the code above I replace:

```
linear_kernel(doc_tfidf, query_tfidf)
```

with

```
df_train['similarity'] = desc_tfidf.multiply(query_tfidf).sum(axis=1)
```

Does this seem like a sane approach? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is typically used to compute the similarity between text documents, which in scikit-learn is implemented in [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html).

However, because [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) also performs a L2 normalization of the results by default (i.e. `norm='l2'`), in this case it is sufficient to compute the dot product to get the cosine similarity.

In your example, you should therefore use,

```
similarity = doc_tfidf.dot(query_tfidf.T).T
```

instead of an element-wise multiplication.